# реализация перегрузки операторов для своего типа

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

всё просто, как реализовать присваивание `int mas[] = {1,2,3}` для своего типа данных? спасибо.

Comment: На сколько знаю, это не присваивание, а инициализация.

Comment: тьфу, да. Это именно оно, но как его реализовать непонятно

Comment: Если правильно понимаю, то никак. Можно переопределить оператор присваивания, но его здесь нет. А инициализацию, если не ошибаюсь, переопределить нельзя. Расскажите подробнее, что Вам нужно получить. У меня есть ощущение, что Вы не с того конца копаете. Но возможно я ошибаюсь

Comment: я уже себе ответил. подробнее можно посмотреть тут : https://youtu.be/WpwyxvgsRoY?t=1561

Answer (score 1):

я нашёл : это реализовывается с помощью списка инициализации(initializer list), как перегрузка конструктора класса:
`my_vector(initializer_list<T> lst) {ваш код. }`.
объект класса `lst` имеет различные методы, например size, и итераторы.